# Ionic 3 CPF/CNPJ mask

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm looking for a mask to CPF/CNPJ, for both of this together.
Actually I'm using this [br-masker-ionic-3](https://github.com/amarkes/br-masker-ionic-3) as a solution, but it can't put together cpf and cnpj.

```
<form #signForm="ngForm">
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>CPF/CNPJ</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="tel" name="cgc" ngModel [brmasker]="{mask:'000.000.000-00', len:14}" [brmasker]="{mask:'00.000.000/0000-00', len:18}"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
<ion-item>
```

I need booth mask in one field... please, some tip?

Comment: Any errors....?

Comment: Can you tell me what this means? `CPF/CNPJ`

`

Comment: @Sampath CPF means a brazilian citizen ID, and CNPJ a company ID.

Comment: Oh.. It seems this is for Brazilians :) It seems this repo has wrong info too. It says `ionic 3.9.2`. But Ionic team has released up to `3.7.1` yet :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days looking for a solution I create myself this one simple that works. So I would like to share with the community that solution, and if you want you can improve it and share again. [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-uwd9vt)

> login.html

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>CPF/CNPJ</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="cpf_cnpj" (blur)="cpf_cnpj = format(cpf_cnpj)" name="cpf_cnpj"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button full type="submit" color="sicor" (tap)="login(signForm.value)">Login</button>
</form>
```

> login.ts

```
import { MenuController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  cpf_cnpj = '';
  DECIMAL_SEPARATOR=".";
  GROUP_SEPARATOR=",";
  pureResult: any;
  maskedId: any;
  val: any;
  v: any;

constructor(
  public modalCtrl: ModalController, 
  private alertCtrl: AlertController,
  private menu: MenuController,
  public navCtrl: NavController, 
  ){} 

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
  }
  ionViewWillLeave(){
    this.menu.swipeEnable(true);
  }

  format(valString) {
    if (!valString) {
        return '';
    }
    let val = valString.toString();
    const parts = this.unFormat(val).split(this.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR);
    this.pureResult = parts;
    if(parts[0].length <= 11){
      this.maskedId = this.cpf_mask(parts[0]);
      return this.maskedId;
    }else{
      this.maskedId = this.cnpj(parts[0]);
      return this.maskedId;
    }
};

unFormat(val) {
    if (!val) {
        return '';
    }
    val = val.replace(/\D/g, '');

    if (this.GROUP_SEPARATOR === ',') {
        return val.replace(/,/g, '');
    } else {
        return val.replace(/\./g, '');
    }
};

 cpf_mask(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, ''); //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v = v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2'); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    v = v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2'); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    //de novo (para o segundo bloco de números)
    v = v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/, '$1-$2'); //Coloca um hífen entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    return v;
}

 cnpj(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, ''); //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v = v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1.$2'); //Coloca ponto entre o segundo e o terceiro dígitos
    v = v.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2.$3'); //Coloca ponto entre o quinto e o sexto dígitos
    v = v.replace(/\.(\d{3})(\d)/, '.$1/$2'); //Coloca uma barra entre o oitavo e o nono dígitos
    v = v.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, '$1-$2'); //Coloca um hífen depois do bloco de quatro dígitos
    return v;
}

  public login(formData) { 
       ....you auth code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually BR Masker have this option:

```
[brmasker]="{person: true}"
```

This way the CPF/CNPJ number is formatted automatically!